# How I filter data by backColor in Excel using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I have to take all data, except when the backColor is equal black.
How do it in Excell?

objExcel have a good interation with Excell, but I didn't find a function for take the color.

Answer (score 0):

Read the value of the `.Interior.Color` property of the cell that contains the data.